# Apply where clause on associated table leads to sequelize bad field error

Tags: sql, node.js, sequelize.js

I have 3 tables sale,company and saleItem with the following relations:

```
Sale.belongsTo(Company);
Company.hasMany(Sale);

Sale.hasMany(SaleItem, { as: "items" });
SaleItem.belongsTo(Sale);
```

I want to apply a filter on the company's name I saw that to do that we have to use $ at the start and end but it isnt working. Any ideas where I am going wrong?

When I try to execute the below code I get the error:

```
SqlError: (conn=201, no: 1054, SQLState: 42S22) Unknown column 'company.name' in 'where clause'
  sql: SELECT `sale`.*, `company`.`id` AS `company.id`, `company`.`name` AS `company.name`, `items`.`id` AS `items.id`, `items`.`quantity` AS `items.quantity`, `items`.`price` AS `items.price`, `items`.`description` AS `items.description`, `items`.`margin` AS `items.margin`, `items`.`gst` AS `items.gst`, `items`.`createdAt` AS `items.createdAt`, `items`.`updatedAt` AS `items.updatedAt`, `items`.`saleId` AS `items.saleId`, `items`.`itemId` AS `items.itemId` FROM (SELECT `sale`.`id`, `sale`.`date`, `sale`.`type`, `sale`.`description`, `sale`.`poNumber`, `sale`.`poDate`, `sale`.`paymentType`, `sale`.`gst`, `sale`.`discount`, `sale`.`freight`, `sale`.`status`, `sale`.`saleStatus`, `sale`.`referenceNumber`, `sale`.`ftn`, `sale`.`quotationNumber`, `sale`.`showGST`, `sale`.`invoiceDate`, `sale`.`hasWithholdingTax`, `sale`.`serialNumber`, `sale`.`currency`, `sale`.`createdAt`, `sale`.`updatedAt`, `sale`.`companyId`, `sale`.`customerId` FROM `sale` AS `sale` WHERE `company`.`name` LIKE '%%' AND `sale`.`customerId` = 1 AND `sale`.`status` = 'ACTIVE' ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 0, 15) AS `sale` LEFT OUTER JOIN `company` AS `company` ON `sale`.`companyId` = `company`.`id` LEFT OUTER JOIN `saleItem` AS `items` ON `sale`.`id` = `items`.`saleId` ORDER BY `id` DESC;
```

It works if I dont include the SaleItem table in query
Here is the code

```
 await Sale.findAndCountAll({
        include: [
          {
            model: Company,
            attributes: ["name"],
            as: "company",
          },
          { model: SaleItem, as: "items" },
        ],
        distinct: true,
        where: {
          "$company.name$": { [Op.like]: `%${search}%` },
           customerId:1,
          status: "ACTIVE",
        },
      })
```

Answer (score 0):

If you see the generated SQL, `company.name` WHERE clause is incorrectly added to a subquery, so you can either turn off the subquery or you can add your `where` option within the `include`.

Option 1:

```
await Sale.findAndCountAll({
    ...,
    subQuery: false
})
```

Option 2:

```
await Sale.findAndCountAll({
    include: [
        {
            model: Company,
            attributes: ["name"],
            as: "company",
            where: {
                name: { [Op.like]: `%${search}%` }
            }
        },
        { model: SaleItem, as: "items" },
    ],
    distinct: true,
    where: {
        customerId:1,
        status: "ACTIVE",
    },
})
```